# Cursor of writing in input field lets to top of these after release new versions of Chrome and Firefox

Tags: css, google-chrome, firefox, browser

If there are no symbols, it is at top. If text is writing, it is normal behaviour. Line-height property is same as height of text field.
[image: Not symbols]

[image: there are some symbols]

Before new releases, there are was same normal behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

Chrome new version issue (Chrome/38.0.2096.0):

https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=426802&thanks=426802&ts=1414143535